# Build a tree from database

Tags: php, algorithm

I recently received a job task to organize an array, the database is not well organized.

The data as example:

```
ID           LEVEL
1000000000     1
1100000000     2
1110000000     3
1111000000     4
1111010000     5
1111010001     6
1111010002     6
1111010003     6
1120000000     3
1121020037     6
1123000000     4
2000000000     1
```

I must organize it by level and adding the bigger level inside the lower level. The main goal here is to create a Tree, to expand the data and the numbers.

```
1 - 1000000000
1.1 - 1100000000
1.1.1 - 1110000000
1.2 - 1200000000
1.2.1 - 1210000000
2 - 2000000000
```

I'm trying to do it more than a week.

```
function buildTree(array &$elements, $parentId = 0) {
    $branch = array();
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $cc = preg_replace("/0+$/", "", $element['cd_conta_estrutural']);
        if ($cc == $parentId) {
            $children = $this->buildTree($elements, $cc);
            if ($children) {
                $element['children'] = $children;
            }
            $branch[$cc] = $element;
            unset($elements[$cc]);
        }
    }
    return $branch;
}
```

If it's not possible, is there another option?

Best regards.

Comment: How "deep" should the tree be ? a depth of 10 ?

Comment: I'm able to follow your tree example up to 1.1.1, how does 1111010000 translate to 2 - 2000000000?

Comment: It will go until leve 6. When it's 2 it means it restarted. The data I receive it's not so good, that's why it's necessary to create parent's and childs.

Comment: When it jumps it's means there is no other below the 3, just the 6. It's hard to me to explain, but the main goal is to enter inside the levels, I'm trying to explode the chars and iterate over then by the number of the level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
$a = [
    ['id'=>1000000000,'level'=>1],
    ['id'=>1100000000,'level'=>2],
    ['id'=>1110000000,'level'=>3],
    ['id'=>1111000000,'level'=>4],
    ['id'=>1111010000,'level'=>5],
    ['id'=>1111010001,'level'=>6],
    ['id'=>1111010002,'level'=>6],
    ['id'=>1111010003,'level'=>6],
    ['id'=>1120000000,'level'=>3],
    ['id'=>1121020037,'level'=>6],
    ['id'=>1123000000,'level'=>4],
    ['id'=>2000000000,'level'=>1],
];


function makeTree($array, $level=1){
    $branch = [];
    foreach($array as $item){
        if($item['level'] == $level){
             $branch[] = $item;
        }else if($item['level'] > $level){
            $branch['children'] = [];
            $branch['children'] = array_merge($branch['children'],makeTree($array,$level+1));
        }

    }
    return $branch;
}

print_r(makeTree($a));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1000000000
            [level] => 1
        )

    [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1100000000
                    [level] => 2
                )

            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1110000000
                            [level] => 3
                        )

                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1111000000
                                    [level] => 4
                                )

                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1111010000
                                            [level] => 5
                                        )

                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 1111010001
                                                    [level] => 6
                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 1111010002
                                                    [level] => 6
                                                )

                                            [2] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 1111010003
                                                    [level] => 6
                                                )

                                            [3] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 1121020037
                                                    [level] => 6
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1123000000
                                    [level] => 4
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1120000000
                            [level] => 3
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2000000000
            [level] => 1
        )

)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fcdad95b34a33c37879104d1055ee77acaa5d6e8)

If you want it organized a little better you can set the key for children before anything else. Like this

```
 function makeTree($array, $level=1){
   $branch = ['children' => []];
    foreach($array as $item){
        if($item['level'] == $level){
             $branch[] = $item;
        }else if($item['level'] > $level){
             $branch['children'] = array_merge($branch['children'],makeTree($array,$level+1));
        }
    }
    return $branch;
 }
```

Personally I would add a key in for the current level.

```
 function makeTree($array, $level=1){
   $branch = ['leafs' => [], 'children' => []];
    foreach($array as $item){
        if($item['level'] == $level){
             $branch['leafs'][] = $item;
        }else if($item['level'] > $level){
             $branch['children'] = array_merge($branch['children'],makeTree($array,$level+1));
        }
    }
    return $branch;
 }
```

Which gives you this

```
Array
(
    [leafs] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1000000000
                    [level] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2000000000
                    [level] => 1
                )

        )

    [children] => Array
        (
            [leafs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1100000000
                            [level] => 2
                        )

                )

            [children] => Array
                (
                    [leafs] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1110000000
                                    [level] => 3
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1120000000
                                    [level] => 3
                                )

                        )

                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [leafs] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1111000000
                                            [level] => 4
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1123000000
                                            [level] => 4
                                        )

                                )

                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [leafs] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 1111010000
                                                    [level] => 5
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [leafs] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 1111010001
                                                            [level] => 6
                                                        )

                                                    [1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 1111010002
                                                            [level] => 6
                                                        )

                                                    [2] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 1111010003
                                                            [level] => 6
                                                        )

                                                    [3] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 1121020037
                                                            [level] => 6
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

But whatever you want.

I should mention it won't break if you are missing a level, it will just put an empty one in for that one.  With a bit of work that could be avoided, but it's not really specified in the question.

Your attempt was very close you just substited ID for level.  I don't think you really care what the ID is, for example `['id'=>2000000000,'level'=>1]` this is not in level #2. And another example is this ID `1111010003` what level is that if not the one listed.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late answer. I'm studying your code, it works, the main feature I'm trying to do is to keep the levels inside the array, not by separated values. Like this: [0] => [all_data, childrens => [ level2, childres => level3 ] ]. With your code, I think I'm able to configure it as I need it this time.

Answer (score 0):

Based at @ArtisticPhoenix code.

The code ended as follow.

```
private function buildTree(&$dados, $level = 1) {    
    $branch = [];    
    foreach($dados as $i => $item) {

        $cc = substr($item['cd_conta_estrutural'], 0, $level);

        if (!isset($dados[$i])) continue;    

        if ($item['id_nivel'] == $level) {    
            $branch[$cc] = $item;    
            unset($dados[$i]);    
        }
        else if ($item['id_nivel'] > $level) {    
            $branch[$cc]['children'] = [];    
            $branch[$cc]['children'] = array_merge($branch[$cc]['children'], $this->buildTree($dados,$level + 1));

        }
        else if ($item['id_nivel'] < $level)
            return $branch;
    }
    return $branch;
}
```

Thanks for all the support.

Best regard's.